# How can I subtract various dates in a single row in a single column

Tags: python, date, dataframe, subtraction, days

I am trying this code in Python.

```
 count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
count4=0
for i in range(len(col_1)):
  a=col_1[i]
  for j in range(len(a)-1):
    delta=pd.to_datetime(a[j])-pd.to_datetime(a[j+1])
    x=delta.days
    if(x>=0)and(x<30):
      count1=count1+1
    elif(x>30)and (x<=60):
      count2=count2+1
    elif(x>=60) and (x<=90):
      count3=count3+1
    else:
      count4=count4+1
```

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhXwv.png)

I am looking to get the number of days by subtracting the various dates .

['2019-05-01',
  '2019-06-01',
  '2019-07-01',
  '2019-08-01',
  '2019-09-01',
  '2019-10-03',
  '2019-11-01']

As we can see the first subtraction will reveal 30 days , the subtraction from the third date with the second date will reveal 30 days and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['dates'])
df.dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-05-01', periods=6, freq='MS')

df['delta_days'] = df.dates.diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Element of list **col1[i]** is a int type according to error you are getting. I don't know why, since col1 is not provided. Assuming col1 is a list with date strings, idk why second iteration is needed:

```
for i in range(len(col1) - 1):
    a = pd.to_datetime(col1[i]).dayofyear
    b = pd.to_datetime(col1[i+1]).dayofyear
    if (a-b)>=0:
        #whatever you want to calculate
```

The second for loop in your code is iterating thru every letter of a date string.